# Low cost barometric pressure sensor

Tags: sensor

I'm looking for a very low cost barometric pressure sensor. The SCP1000-D01 available at Sparkfun and elsewhere is around $25 but I was hoping to find something in the $5-10 range. I am only interested in rough relative pressure change, so it does not have to have high precision or be calibrated. Basically something like the thermistor equivalent for pressure...

Comment: tough question! -- i'll ask around at work when I get a chance -- there's some Japanese company that makes some pressure sensors that are low cost.... although it could be that they are just low cost in high volumes.

Comment: I just had this exact same question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Futurlec has a few barometric sensor in the $5-10 range. These use I2C interface though, so a bit more involved in the MCU side than a simple analog voltage.

http://www.futurlec.com/Pressure_Sensors.shtml

If you're in Australia, you can buy from their Australian website as well.

Answer (score 5):

I would take a look at the sensors from Freescale.  I bought an [MPX4115A from Mouser.com](http://www.mouser.com/Search/ProductDetail.aspx?R=MPX4115Avirtualkey55700000virtualkey841-MPX4115A) for about $10.  This is (supposedly) suitable for use as an altimeter; I haven't gotten to that project, yet. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can check out the Bosch Sensortec BMP085 sensor. It is SMT, but it gave me [good results.](http://interactive-matter.org/2009/12/arduino-barometric-pressure-sensor-bmp085/)

Comment: I still have some - so if anybody is interested - hit the contact button on my site ;)

Comment: BMP085 is good if you don't need anything too high resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Those Freescale devices are very easy to use - I'd interface it to a small MCU with an ADC. Alternatively, you could just connect it to a voltmeter.

Answer (score 1):

Another vote for the MPX4115 family - I'm using one, they're very simple to use & cheap.