# Pressure activated switch for a light up LED straw? Similar to how a vape pen activates with air pressure drop when sucking?

Tags: switches, pressure

I’m looking for a component that I can integrate into an LED straw so that when the user starts sucking on it the light turns on. What should I be looking at? I disassembled a Juul pod and see that there are two leads that connect when you suck on them, although if that is inside of the straw while liquid is moving over it might not be ideal.

Any ideas?

Comment: Separate tube that only allows air for the wires?

Comment: The "suck to activate" (there should really be a better term for that) feature of a vape only works because the unit is sealed. When you inhale you are pulling a vacuum which can be measured. Not sure you can accomplish the same thing with an open tube without having things inside of the straw. A "turbine" of some sort could work.

Comment: Rising liquid would detune a free running UHF oscillator connected to a thin wire along the outside of the straw... The change in air volume inside the straw would change the acoustic resonance frequency... A resistor or diode, warmed up by current, would cool down a bit from the air flow...

Comment: You should provide more details re what the straw is used for. Does it suck up fluid and activate then - or migh you suck in air only and want it to light. Or ... ?

Comment: It sucks liquid through it and lights up as soon as the user starts sucking.

Comment: A simple solution will be to have two contact point at both ends of the straw, so when liquid fills the tube, the two points are connected together. Use this signal to control a FET that turns on and off LEDs.

Answer (score 1):

*My understanding is you're designing a novelty LED straw which lights up when a drink is sucked through it*

### Back-of-envelope parameters

- The length of the straw is 100 mm
- Thus there is a pressure drop of approx 1 kPa ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centimetre_or_millimetre_of_water))
- Sucking time is about 5 seconds
- Desired response time < 0.1 sec
- The drink is likely to be about 3 °C ([Recommended by drinks company](https://hvacseer.com/how-to-adjust-temperature-on-coca-cola-fridge/))
- Drinks are likely to vary and might be transparent, orange, brown, white and might have particulates or be filtered (water, milk, juice, iced coffee, sodas, cocktails)
- Drinks may be carbonated, acidic, alkaline, salty, sweet
- Drinks might be viscous (milkshake) or not (water)
- Device must be cleanable

I'll assume you have something like this and can put together T-junctions to measure at.
[image]

### Method 1: Atmospheric Pressure Sensor

Use a device such as [MPL3115A2](http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Pressure/MPL3115A2.pdf) which is designed for use as an altimeter in drones, with accuracy of approx 1 m in altitude.

Our 1 Kpa drop is equivalent to about 100 metres or altitude, so the range is about right.([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_pressure#Altitude_variation))

- Pro: Small, easy to interface
- Con: Might need some kind of membrane between drink and sensor, physical interface a little tricky

### Method 2: General Pressure Sensore

Consider a device such as [Honeywell Micropressure Sensor](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/2/e/8/0/9/honeywell-mpr-datasheet.pdf) which is for measuring pressures in liquids!

- Pro: "compatible with liquids", small, easy physical interface
- Con: Cleaning?

### Method 3: Optomechanical

A hole in the straw can be covered with a flexible membrane.  This moves when the internal pressure changes, which is then detected by any photosensing method.  Any flexible tube will move under pressure change, or a pipette or dropper head.

- Pro: potentially simple.  Flexible rubber tube might be replacable

### Method 4: Optical

Many drinks absorb ultraviolet light.  So a sinple UV LED and photodiode pair might well detect drinks.

- Pro: No contact with the drink
- Con: Needs testing

### Method 5: Thermal

If the drinks are cold, a thermosensor will detect it.  There are endless, from analogue to digital, but one with direct threshold outputs is the [AS6212](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/f/a/6/c/8/AS621x_DS000677_2-00.pdf)

- Pro: nice and simple, no contact with drink
- Con: response time slow in comparison, perhaps 1 sec

Comment: I wonder if the application allows to substitute sensing of the pressure drop in the straw with sensing the presence of liquid in the top part of the straw.  Inspired by Method 4.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having two metal plates on both sides. Water has a much higher dielectric constant than air. By using 1 Darlington pair you could most certainly detect this change in capacitance and use it to power an LED.

Answer (score 1):

On a non- conducting tube print conducting pads along its length on one side. On the opposite print a solid conducting pad along the entire length. The linear array of capacitors will allow detection the height of water in the straw. LEDs can then be turned on in a sequence driven by the height.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution in my opinion is one which does not have moving parts or sensors that depend on what the user does with the straw. Even if they drink room temperature vodka with it, it should work correctly. This rules out temperature, color, pressure, and many other methods. Two thoughts:

**Fully encased microphone (Diffifculty: parsing signal)**

If the microphone is fully encased in the straw material alongside the electronics, it should be fully washable, and would only really "hear" or focus on conducted sound waves. I imagine that there would be a sound signature for the user's lips touching the tip of the straw, and then sucking would produce a slight vibratio/sound which may be picked up. To try this method, tape the headphones of any earbuds to a straw, connect to your computer and using software like Audacity record and try to analyze any interesting trends in sound. I dont think this problem is fundimentally different to the clap on/off switches, you just need to detect some predefined pattern.

**Capacitive (Difficulty: liquid viscocity)**

You can get really creative with a capacitive solution. Lets look at two things you can do. 1- Capacitive slider, as seen below (I think geometry one works better for this usecase)
[image: Capacitive sliding sensor, made with two complementary interwoven comb like structures, usually used to allow the MCU to determine finger position.]
Source: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/Atmel-42479-Capacitive-Touch-Long-Slider-Design-with-PTC_AT11805_ApplicationNote.pdf
[image: Capacitive sliding sensor, made with two complementary triangles which form a square together, so that the ratio changes along the length, usually used to allow the MCU to determine finger position from this ratio.]
Source: https://www.matrixtsl.com/webshop/capacitive-touch-slider-sensor-module.html

This slider type sensor allows for two things: When the straw is inserted into the drink, some animation can be played. As soon as the liquid level moves up, the capacitance changes (many microcontrollers have ready libraries for this kind of touch sensor which make this easier to implement). Problem: what if the user adds liquid while straw is in the drink? it may be confused with them sucking. If that's something you care about, think about:

2- A capacitive ring on the top of the straw (or both ends if straw is reversible). This allows there to be an "interlock", which only plays the sucking animation if user's lips touch the straw and liquid level rises. Alternatively, a "lossy" approximation of the user sucking is just them placing their lip onto the staw, so you wouldnt need the sliding sensor.

The problem with this method is that the liquid may just stay on the straw's edges after the first use, which may happen for example if they drink a thick milkshake. Even if the resulting layer is thin, I think it will be sufficient for the capacitance sensor to staturate.

---

What I would probably do is use the microphone alongside with a capacitive sensor for the lips at either end as an interlock. The user will need both capacitive sensors activated before the straw turns on (the bottom one by the drink, the top one by their lips. This allows protection from the straw being needlessly "woken up" by a spoon getting near one sensor while in storage). Even if something like a milkshake keeps the capacitive sensor engaged, the mic will have the final say in turning on the LEDs, and the power expended by keeping the mic for a little while isnt horrible. The capacitive sensor will allow you to keep the straw's MCU in a low power sleep mode, and when activated you can run the mic to process whether the user is sucking.

Answer (score 0):

To keep it food-safe a capacitive or inductive sensor might be a good idea.
There are industrial-type I2C connected sensors available if this is a one-off otherwise most modern microcontrollers (esp32 f.i.) support touch input which might be utilizable for this matter.

Also copper plates on both sides could be a method as the capacity will change when the "dielectric" changes from air to liquid.

Temperature change is also an option: Use a sensor that heats up over ambient temp which is thermic coupled to the straw.

Answer (score 0):

A barometric pressure sensor could do this. Baro sensors measure absolute pressure, so you could measure the vacuum and  thus estimate the height of the liquid in the straw from it if you wanted to do a fancy animation of some sort.

Related: [Low cost barometric pressure sensor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1324/low-cost-barometric-pressure-sensor)

Difficulty: keeping the sensor port clean.